# DEM raster data to another raster with different resolution and extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem

I have two raster datasets:

One fine resolution DGM and another one, with different resolution, in which I want to have the mean elevation from the DEM (if possible the mean of the cells from the DGM which intersects it)

The raster have different resolution and different extend.

[image: Image 1]

How can I get the data from my DEM to my other raster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) or [Zonal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm) depending upon your intended output. These tools perform an internal resampling if the spatial resolution does not match.

> If the resolutions are different, an internal resampling is applied to
>   make them match before the zonal operation is performed.

Comment: I was using it before and got wrong results. I found my error:
I only had values of 1 and 0 in my raster. I changed them to 1 to n and now its calulating for each different cell. Thank you